# export table data using mysql command (not mysqldump)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do an export of a table and we do not have mysqldump installed.

I thought I can do this:

`root:~> mysql news media > news.media.7.26.2016.sql`

where `news is the database name and media is the table name`

it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Are you able to execute a php script to dump the table?

Comment: @SamOrozco no i just thought that exposing mysql question to php would be wise seeing how its part of the lamp stack.

Comment: is there a reason you can't install mysql dump?, edited the comment

Comment: @SamOrozco we do not have this installed its a custom mysql installation

Comment: @SamOrozco whats wrong with my command? why cant this work?

Comment: I have no clue why your command isn't working I've never seen anything like that. What if you did something like this: `mysql -e "select * from News" -u root -pmysqlpass Media > news.media.7.26.2016.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Your command tries to mimic `mysqldump` but `mysql` does not have a table parameter. You could run it like this:

```
mysql -D news -e "SELECT * FROM media" > news.media.7.26.2016.txt
```

That will work but you won't get nice SQL statements in the output, just tabular data export.

I mean that you may (or may not) run into problems when importing the data back. There's a chance to use

```
mysql -D news -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'news.media.7.26.2016.txt' INTO TABLE media"
```

but I do not have much experience with that. First of your concerns is secure-file-priv setting that has been made strict starting in MySQL 5.7.6. Second, I would be a tad bit nervous about preserving data types.